# Synaptics touchpad disabled after login after recent 18.10 update

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, libinput

My Synaptic Touchpad stopped working in the past few weeks.

The touchscreen and external mouse still work so I've been using them to work around it.

The symptoms are:

- Touchpad works on login screen
- Touchpad stops working after login screen
- All other inputs work, including keyboard, touchscreen, external mouse, docking station, etc.
- Doesn't work on Wayland, either.
- F7 key comes up with a square with an X in the bottom-right corner, but the X won't go away no matter how many times I press it.
- `sudo rmmod usbhid; sudo modprobe usbhid` enables the touchpad for a split second.

For the previous few weeks, I've been able to resurrect the touchpad with `sudo rmmod usbhid; sudo modprobe usbhid` so I suspect that this issue is in two parts.

`xinput list` shows:

```
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA7500:00 06CB:780B                     id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics T Pad V 01.31 Touchpad          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_FHD: Integrat           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_8M: Rear Inte           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver               id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SYNA7500:00 06CB:780B Pen                 id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Synaptics T Pad V 01.31 Consumer Control  id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Synaptics T Pad V 01.31                   id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Synaptics T Pad V 01.31 Wireless Radio Control    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have tried:

1. Installing the synaptics driver
2. Adding in a libinput filter (which made the `Synaptics T Pad V 01.31 Touchpad` above disappear, but actually made it worse)
3. `xinput set-prop 11 "Device Enabled" 1 (0 followed by 1 as well)
4. `xinput set-prop 16 "Device Enabled" 1 (0 followed by 1 as well)

This is on kernel 4.18.0-15-generic, but I have also tried going back to 4.17 and it doesn't work, either.  I can't roll back to any earlier versions of xserver-xorg-input-* because they don't appear to be available.

I suspect that the touchpad may be programattically disabled (which would explain the X in the F7 status) but I don't know how to programatically re-enable it.

**How do I get my touchpad back?**

Comment: See this answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/624929/167115

Comment: As a user mentions, you may have to toggle the setting by setting "enabled" to 0 and then by setting "enabled" to 1 but hopefully setting it to 1 the first time will work. If not, please let me know because there may be a different solution.

Comment: Also, does the cursor appear on the screen? Sometimes the cursor disappears and so it seems like the touchpad is not working but, in fact, the touchpad is working fine but the cursor is invisible.

Comment: No, there is no activity from the touchpad.  I've seen that before.

Comment: Plus, this also happened to my boss with the same machine just days apart.

Comment: Did you try switching to tty1 by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1 and then use F7 or fn+F7 and then press CTRL+ALT+F7 to switch back to your xsession to see if that works? https://askubuntu.com/a/191048/167115

Comment: Also, the touchpad indicator may be interfering if that is installed or enabled.

Answer (score 0):

**According to the [Ubuntu help docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad#Touchpad_not_working_after_login)**, this problem is often solved using the following command:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled true
```

---

**You can also enable or toggle the touchpad using `synclient` instead of `xinput`.**

To enable:

```
synclient touchpadoff=0
```

To toggle:

```
synclient touchpadoff=1
synclient touchpadoff=0
```

Additionally, you could try using a different device listed like device 16 instead of 11:

```
xinput set-prop 16 "Device Enabled" 1
```

**[click here for additional information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad)**

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a similar problem with the exact same model of touchpad on Fedora.

The culprit in my case was fwupd, which gets started by GNOME software upon login. Fwupd scans for possibly updateable devices and reading the journal I found out the touchpad did not like the requests made by fwupd and and passed out.

Masking the service fwupd using `systemctl mask fwupd.service` solved this problem for me.